# How come I can't load system information from a node.js file into my electron html page?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, electron, system-information

I am working on a project which is a client mod for a popular crypto miner. I got permission from the owners and everything. I am having an issue with loading system information from my node,js script `systeminfo.js` and putting it into the electron index.html file.

When I view the electron page it simply just shows the placeholder text that was already in the html. Does anyone know how I can resolve this issue? Do I need to mention the index.html in the node.js code?

This is my node.js code:

```
const si = require('systeminformation');

async function getSystemInfo() {
    try {
        const gpuData = await si.graphics();
        const cpuData = await si.cpuTemperature();
        const cpuUsage = await si.currentLoad();

        const gpuName = gpuData.controllers[0].model;
        const gpuTemp = gpuData.controllers[0].temperatureGpu;
        const gpuUsage = gpuData.controllers[0].loadGpu;

        const cpuName = cpuData.main;

        // Access the DOM elements using Electron's API
        const gpuNameElement = document.getElementById('gpuName');
        const gpuTempElement = document.getElementById('gpuTemp');
        const gpuUsageElement = document.getElementById('gpuUsage');
        const cpuNameElement = document.getElementById('cpuName');
        const cpuTempElement = document.getElementById('cpuTemp');

        // Populate GPU information in HTML
        gpuNameElement.innerText = `GPU Name: ${gpuName}`;
        gpuTempElement.innerText = `GPU Temp: ${gpuTemp} °C`;
        gpuUsageElement.innerText = `GPU Usage: ${gpuUsage}%`;

        // Populate CPU information in HTML
        cpuNameElement.innerText = `CPU Name: ${cpuName}`;
        cpuTempElement.innerText = `CPU Temp: ${cpuData.main} °C`;

    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error:', error);
    }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    getSystemInfo();
});
```

Then this is the snippet of my html where I am trying to load the information into:

```
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="systemPanel" role="tabpanel">
                        <script src="systeminfo.js"></script>
                        <br>
                        <h1 style="color: white;">System Info</h1>
                        <p style="color: white;">This is a list of information about your system.</p>
                        <br>
                        <div style="display: flex; align-items: center;">
                            <h3 style="margin-right: 10px; color: white;">GPU Information</h3>
                            <img src="resources/gpu.png" width="30px" height="30px" style="filter: brightness(100%) grayscale(100%) invert(100%); vertical-align: middle;">
                        </div>
                        <p id="gpuName" style="color: white;">GPU Name: </p>
                        <p id="gpuTemp" style="color: white;">GPU Temp: </p>
                        <p id="gpuUsage" style="color: white;">GPU Usage: </p>
                        <div style="display: flex; align-items: center;">
                            <h3 style="margin-right: 10px; color: white;">CPU Information</h3>
                            <img src="resources/cpu.png" width="30px" height="30px" style="filter: brightness(100%) grayscale(100%) invert(100%); vertical-align: middle;">
                        </div>
                        <p id="cpuName" style="color: white;">CPU Name: </p>
                        <p id="cpuTemp" style="color: white;">CPU Temp: </p>
                    </div>
```

Does anyone have any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Sorry about the weird indenting in the html, I don't know why it did that.

Comment: `This is my node.js code:` is that `systeminfo.js`? What errors do you see in the browser *developer* tools console? Did you know that `systeminforamtion` is a node only module and won't run inside a browser? per documentation **Attention: this is a node.js library. It is supposed to be used as a backend/server-side library and will definitely not work within a browser.**

Comment: @JaromandaX Oh, so is there a way to get to my end goal using something else like an electron optimised library?

Comment: are you trying to show the "system information" of the server or the "client"?

Comment: @JaromandaX client

Answer (score 0):

For [security](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/security#2-do-not-enable-nodejs-integration-for-remote-content) reasons, by default you can't use Node.js in your [renderer process](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/process-model#the-renderer-process). If you need to get data from a Node.js code, you can use [IPC](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/ipc) and a [preload](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/tutorial-preload) file. For example:

**Main**

```js
ipcMain.handle("getSystemInfo", () => {
  // Get the data you need and return them...
});
```

**Preload**

```js
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require('electron');

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('electronAPI', {
  getSystemInfo: () => ipcRenderer.invoke("getSystemInfo")
});
```

**Renderer**

```js
const systemInfo = await window.electronAPI.getSystemInfo();
```

---

Also be aware that, by default, [processes](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/process-model) are [isolated](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/context-isolation) and [sandboxed](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/sandbox).

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the reply. Does this mean by default I can't make the client show system info of the user without the user enabling something?

Comment: @Mapler No, it has nothing to do with the user, please read the docs I linked, everything is explained on them. The first link about security in particular.